# Warning: Prop className mismatch between server and client rendering in React SSR application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am currently working on implementing a collapsible sidebar in my React application that relies on a value stored in the local storage. The desired behavior is that if the value is true, the sidebar should have the className of "inline," and if the value is false, the className of "hidden" should be applied.

The implementation of the logic seems to be working as expected, and I am getting the desired result. However, I am encountering the following warning in the browser:

```
Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "hidden" Client: "inline"
```

My assumption is that the code itself is functioning correctly. However, when comparing the state between the server and the client, it appears that the server-rendered content takes precedence and always shows the className as "hidden" instead of what should actually be applied.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```js
  const checkExpanded = () => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      const sidebarState = localStorage.getItem("sidebarState");
      if (sidebarState) {
        return JSON.parse(sidebarState);
      }
      return true;
    }
  };

  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(checkExpanded());

  const toggleExpanded = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };

  // fetch sidebar state from local storage
  useEffect(() => {
    const sidebarState = localStorage.getItem("sidebarState");
    if (sidebarState) {
      setExpanded(JSON.parse(sidebarState));
    }
  }, []);

  // save sidebar state to local storage
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("sidebarState", JSON.stringify(expanded));
  }, [expanded]);


  <span className={expanded ? "inline" : "hidden"}>{item.text}</span>
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to address this warning and ensure that the client-rendered className matches the expected value. Thank you in advance for your help!

Here are the attempted solutions I have already tried:

I verified that the value from the local storage is being read correctly. I ensured that the value retrieval from localStorage.getItem("sidebarState") is functioning as expected.

I investigated whether the value of the sidebar state is being changed anywhere else during runtime. After thorough examination, I concluded that the issue does not lie in the code where the value is modified.

Despite these efforts, the warning persists. It suggests that the mismatch between the server-rendered and client-rendered className props is not caused by a direct issue with the value or its modification.

Comment: What happens when this condition evaluate to false `typeof window !== "undefined"`. What would be the expanded state value in that case?

Comment: Also the useEffect with empty dependancy looks redundant to me. You are already setting the state in useState when component is initialised.

Comment: Nothing happens if the `typeof window !== "undefined"`. Should anything happen here since it's unmounted. And yes I think the useEffect does become redundant so I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is [import the component dynamically](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#with-no-ssr) and disable ssr. It would resolve the errors caused by using any browser APIs like `window`

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
 
const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() => import('../components'), {
  ssr: false,
})
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It works fine with the error mentioned not there anymore. But the component is not there for a brief moment when I reload the page. Could you explain why that is happening as I am new to this framework. Thank you.

Comment: That is because by dynamically loading the component and adding the `ssr` flag false, we are essentially telling the nextjs not to render this component on the server and just load it on the client. That is why there is a brief moment when the component loads on the client.

Comment: I kind of solved the problem by removing the `checkExpanded()` function overall and using null as my initial value for expanded. The error is not there but the behavior is also not what I envisioned. I wanted to display the sidebar based on the user's previous action (If the user had the sidebar extended previously, it should have that state even if the page is reloaded, and same when the sidebar is collapsed). But I guess that is out of the box, since I cannot read from `localStorage` until the window is mounted or something. Again thank you for your suggestion as I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

The problem being that `window` is not defined on the server side. Therefore expand is null on the server side and true on the client side.
And so :

```
<span className={expanded ? "inline" : "hidden"}>{item.text}</span>
```

Worth hidden on the server side and inline on the client side

Comment: Is there any way I can solve this? I want the client side to be prioritized I guess since it is an interactive component.